# "read" action is pending for more than a month

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action

I`m waiting for more than a month for fb to approve my 'read' action, 
I followed the requaerments and did everything correctly.
what can I do?
My app ID: 266318970102843

Thanks

Comment: Any idea? what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you provided detailed instructions on how actions work and how Facebook can easily test the actions. E.g:

1. Provide a test user account for Facebook to use (create one from the 'Roles' page on the App Settings area.
2. Provide step-by-step instructions into logging in, preforming an action, and how the user can remove the action manually from your site.

I was able to get my action approved in just 2 days. I recommend cancelling the action and submitting it again with detailed instructions. Then hopefully you will receive a message like this in a few days:

> Thank you for your Open Graph Action submission. The Open Graph Action
>   [Action] used in [Your App] has been approved.
>
> This Action is now visible to all users.